# Chaincode installation written in javascript on peer in HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I create a chaincode package with the following command:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode package fabcar.tar.gz --path /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/fabcar/javascript --label fabcar_1 --lang node
```

I try to install this package on a peer

```
peer lifecycle chaincode install fabcar.tar.gz
```

The command fails

```
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "+ INPUT_DIR=/chaincode/input
+ OUTPUT_DIR=/chaincode/output
+ cp -R /chaincode/input/src/. /chaincode/output
+ cd /chaincode/output
+ '[' -f package-lock.json -o -f npm-shrinkwrap.json ]
+ npm install --production
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/fabric-contract-api failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-08T14_35_36_142Z-debug.log
```

[Snapshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwx29.png)

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the chaincode container timed out trying to use DNS to resolve registry.npmjs.org. I don't know what environment you are using to run your Fabric nodes, or why DNS name resolution isn't working there, but that appears to be the problem you need to solve.

Comment: I installed Hyperledger Fabric with Bevel. So, the fabric nodes are running in k8s pods.